# Django FileNotFoundError at /admin/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media'

Tags: django, admin, media, filenotfounderror

Website works fine locally but when I try to change or add to the model Trick (which has a FilePathField attribute) in localhost:8000/admin, I get FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media'.

---

```
/login_unecessary_tricks_list/models.py
from django.db import models

class Trick(models.Model):
    video = models.FilePathField(path='/media')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
```

---

```
/project/settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

---

```
/project/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path("", include('login_unnecessary_tricks_list.urls')),
path("", include('op_ed_articles .urls')),
] + static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I’m guessing there’s a problem with my media folder implementation, but I don’t know what it is.

Comment: Please post relevant code and errors as text, not as images

Comment: Why `.parent.parent`?  What exactly is your directory structure?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).